# MySQL child data row has muliple parent keys and need to build select query

Tags: mysql

### Parent Table(Animals)

- ID  :
- Name:
- Sex :[*`Male=0`* ,*`Female=1`* ,*`other= -1`*,*`DESEXED - Female=2`*,*`DESEXED - Male =3`*]

[image]

### Transaction Table

- Transaction ID
- Animal_Father_ID
- Animal_Mother_ID
- Animal_Child_ID
- Date
- Status

### Sample Transaction

[image]

With Transaction table now I need to join parent table and needs to get the summary with Animal name like;

[image]

How I used select statement with joining **Parent Table(Animals)** And get above result ?

*(previous developer create this structure and it's have almost 20GB data. Now I can't change the table structure)*

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 1
   t.ID,
   p.Name as 'Name of Father',
   m.Name as 'Name of Mother',
   c.Name as 'Name if Child',
   t.Date,
   t.Status
FROM Transactions t
JOIN Animals m ON m.ID = t.Animal_Mother_ID
JOIN Animals p ON p.ID = t.Animal_Father_ID
JOIN Animals c ON c.ID = t.Animal_Child_ID
```

Comment: This returns only one even I removed top 1

Answer (score 1):

I am riffing off of koryakinp's answer, but adding in a case statement to transform the value of the status:

```
SELECT 
   t.Transaction_ID,
   p.Name as 'Name of Father',
   m.Name as 'Name of Mother',
   c.Name as 'Name if Child',
   t.Date,
   CASE 
    WHEN t.Status = 1 THEN 'Active'
    WHEN t.Status = 2 THEN 'Value2'
    WHEN t.Status = 3 THEN 'Value3'
    WHEN t.Status = 4 THEN 'Value4'
    WHEN t.Status = 5 THEN 'Value5'
    ELSE t.Status
   END as Status
FROM transaction t
JOIN parent m ON m.ID = t.Animal_Mother_ID
JOIN parent p ON p.ID = t.Animal_Father_ID
JOIN parent c ON c.ID = t.Animal_Child_ID
```

and without the case statement:

```
SELECT 
   t.Transaction_ID,
   p.Name as 'Name of Father',
   m.Name as 'Name of Mother',
   c.Name as 'Name if Child',
   t.Date
FROM transaction t
JOIN parent m ON m.ID = t.Animal_Mother_ID
JOIN parent p ON p.ID = t.Animal_Father_ID
JOIN parent c ON c.ID = t.Animal_Child_ID
```

Comment: I just remove status record column from the result but it's always show only one row? Do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: I created a test database with the tables and data you showed in your question and it returned 2 rows as expected. I am not sure why it would return only one row. Can you show us the exact query you used? I assume the table and column names shown in your question are the same in your db?